# Error while displaying an Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I get the following error, and i have no clue how to avoid it, can someone please help me

**bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x1ea990: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...**

```
 - (void)loadImg {
        NSData* image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://images.sugarscape.com/userfiles/image/DECEMBER2010/Lozza/HarryStyles2.jpg"]];
        UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:image] ;
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showImg:) withObject:img];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call any UIKit methods from threads other than the main thread. `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` executes `showImg:` on a secondary thread, and if you call any UIKit methods there, that might be the problem.

It is actually explained in plain English:

> This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread

Comment: @sharon If `loadImg` is executed on the main thread, just replace the last line with `[self showImg: img];`.

Comment: You mean to remove ` [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showImg:) withObject:img];` and replace it with `[self showImg: img];` ?

Comment: Yes. Have you explored the absolute basics of iOS programming yet? This is a basic method call.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe to update UI from a background thread, which I am assuming you are doing here

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showImg:) withObject:img];
```

I think you may have got it the wrong way round you want to:

1. Retrieve the image on a background thread
2. Update the UI with this image on the main thread

Comment: How can i do it programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Threading Programmin Guide: Thread Safety Summary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-123351-BBCFIIEB), you should invoke UIView's operations on main thread. Try [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImg:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES].

Comment: I get the same error when i use `performSelectorOnMainThread`

Comment: Hi Sharon, I think it would be better to run with Debug scheme to find which line your application crash. Then you can check which thread it runs on.